# How to save multiple logins in .env file for connecting to postgresql databse?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a .env file in the following format:

```
PGUSER=
PGPASSWORD=
PGDATABSE=
PGHOST=
PGPORT=
```

To use the credentials stored in the file, I use the following code (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423251/how-can-i-make-a-psycopg2-connection-using-environment-variables)):

```
import psycopg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
conn = psycopg2.connect('')
```

This connects me successfully to the database.

My question now is how I can store and choose login details for multiple databases in this .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done using one .evn. I'd suggest creating .ini file and using `configparser` to choose between sections.

Here you can find great [example](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/)

Comment: It can be done, it would just involve more work. You would have to preface the variables with a db name e.g. `DB1_PGUSER=` and then pull out those settings that apply and pass to `psycopg2.connect()`.

Comment: Yep, I should answer more precisely :P It can't be done with single .env and `conn = psycopg2.connect('')`  used in question.
-1 for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I use `FLASK` and it can use `dotenv` with its own custom file `.flaskenv` in addition to `.env`. That pointed to be able to using multiple files. Basically what they do is:

```
load_dotenv(find_dotenv('.some_file'))
```

So that is an option.